# I need to extract data from a SOAP message

Tags: xml, postgresql

Using PostgreSQL 9.6.

An application stores a SOAP message in a column.
I need the value within an XML tag in the SOAP body part to be stored in a new column.

I tried LTRIM, XPATH, SUBSTRING and SPLIT_PART, but it is not working.
I suspect XPATH not working because it is not recognizing the SOAP message as XML.

Below is an example of the SOAP message, for readability I entered line breaks manually. In the Database it is stored without line breaks. I separated the part that I need.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <SOAP-ENV:Body>
    <ns0:PRLGOnDemandCreatePdfBasicV1Request xmlns:ns0="http://www.aiasoftware.com/cloud/v1">
    <ns0:partner/>
    <ns0:customer>G0013860xEC3Dx86C4xEC7Dx4857xB80Dx5E99x0D98xACDD</ns0:customer>
    <ns0:contracttypename/>
    <ns0:contracttypeversion/>
    <ns0:jobid>685769936602576682270215144939</ns0:jobid>
    <ns0:documenttemplate>Template1</ns0:documenttemplate>
    <ns0:isconcept/>

    <ns0:databackbonexml>Part I need</ns0:databackbonexml>

    <ns0:status/>
    </ns0:PRLGOnDemandCreatePdfBasicV1Request>
    </SOAP-ENV:Body>
    </SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

This is the XPath query I tried:

```
xpath_exists('/y:PRLGOnDemandCreatePdfBasicV1Request/y:databackbonexml/text()',
    esb_berichten.esb_request::xml, 
    array[array['y', 'aiasoftware.com/cloud/v1']]),
xpath('/x:databackbonexml/text()', 
    esb_berichten.esb_request::xml, 
    array[array['x','aiasoftware.com/cloud/v1']])
```

This is my query:

```
SELECT 
xpath_exists('/y:PRLGOnDemandCreatePdfBasicV1Request/y:databackbonexml/text()',
    esb_berichten.esb_request::xml, 
    array[array['y', 'aiasoftware.com/cloud/v1']]),
xpath('/x:databackbonexml/text()', 
    esb_berichten.esb_request::xml, 
    array[array['x','aiasoftware.com/cloud/v1']])
FROM 
  public.esb_berichten
WHERE esb_berichten.esb_service = 'RMD_SmartDocuments_ITP_In_The_Cloud' LIMIT 10;
```

This is the output:

```
xpath_exists|xpath
f|{}
f|{}
```

I kind of solved it. The problem was partly because the column was cast as text, so I had to cast it to XML.

This is whhat I made:

````
    SELECT '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <SOAP-ENV:Body>
    <ns0:PRLGOnDemandCreatePdfBasicV1Request xmlns:ns0="http://www.aiasoftware.com/cloud/v1">
    <ns0:partner/>
    <ns0:customer>G0013860xEC3Dx86C4xEC7Dx4857xB80Dx5E99x0D98xACDD</ns0:customer>
    <ns0:contracttypename/>
    <ns0:contracttypeversion/>
    <ns0:jobid>685769936602576682270215144939</ns0:jobid>
    <ns0:documenttemplate>Template1</ns0:documenttemplate>
    <ns0:isconcept/>
    <ns0:databackbonexml>SXQncyBsdW5jaCB0aW1l</ns0:databackbonexml>
    <ns0:status/>
    </ns0:PRLGOnDemandCreatePdfBasicV1Request>
    </SOAP-ENV:Body>
    </SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
    '::xml
       )
    SELECT
    split_part(split_part(p_xml::text, '<ns0:jobid>', 2), '</ns0:jobid>', 1)  AS jobid,
    split_part(split_part(p_xml::text, '<ns0:documenttemplate>', 2), '</ns0:documenttemplate>', 1) AS documenttemplate,
    split_part(split_part(p_xml::text, '<ns0:isconcept>', 2), '</ns0:isconcept>', 1) AS isconcept,
    split_part(split_part(p_xml::text, '<ns0:databackbonexml>', 2), '</ns0:databackbonexml>', 1)::xml AS databackbonexml,
    CONVERT_FROM(DECODE(split_part(split_part(p_xml::text, '<ns0:databackbonexml>', 2), '</ns0:databackbonexml>', 1)::text, 'BASE64'), 'UTF-8') AS decoded
    FROM   tbl;```
````

Comment: Post your actual XPath query instead of assuming that SOAP can't be parsed. SOAP is well-formed XML. You shouldn't be storing an entire SOAP response anyway, but XPATH *can* parse it, if it can be parsed at all. If it can't it means you're missing data, namespaces, or the string is simply wrong. You **can't** parse XML using string splitting

Comment: Why are you storing the entire SOAP message instead of the body???

Comment: I have no influence on this, a supplier puts te entire SOAP message in this column.

I tried:

xpath_exists('/y:PRLGOnDemandCreatePdfBasicV1Request/y:databackbonexml/text()', esb_berichten.esb_request::xml, array[array['y', 'http://www.aiasoftware.com/cloud/v1']]),
xpath('/x:databackbonexml/text()', esb_berichten.esb_request::xml, array[array['x','http://www.aiasoftware.com/cloud/v1']])

I read somewhere that the namespace reference makes it harder.

Comment: This is still valid XML that can be queried with XPath. How did you try to query this? What were the problems? Did you get errors for namespaces perhaps?  You can't parse XML with string splitting? *Post the code and errors in the question itself*

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos: Thansk for your patiance end assistance, this is my first question here. I update my question with the query and the output.